# Уникальные данные в одной колонке pandas

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

```
atrname = 0
for xarik in ff.cssselect('.table_tech li'):
    al = xarik.cssselect('span')[0]
    alfa = al.text
    be = xarik.cssselect('span')[1]
    beta = be.text
    atrname += 1
    aktiv_list.append(('Attribute %s name' % atrname, alfa))
    aktiv_list.append(('Attribute %s value(s)' % atrname, beta))
    aktiv_list.append(('Attribute %s visible' % atrname, 1))
    aktiv_list.append(('Attribute %s global' % atrname, 1))
```

http://pastie.org/p/7uPuSWxWqZx4C10o5SBq5q полный текст

На выходе получается вот такая таблица, скажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы данные в одной таблице были уникальными, а не разными по колонке Attribute 1 name?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итог должен быть таким

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем вы привели код, не релевантный вопросу? приведите пример получившейся таблицы в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы хотите получить. Приведите пример в каком виде вы хотите видеть результат.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил итог

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Если вы думаете, что люди кинутся вбивать данные с картинок лишь для того, чтобы помочь вам, то вы явно переоцениваете желание сообщества помочь вам ;)

Comment: @MaxU добавил полный код